# How do I link individual letters to a word?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am creating a word game where you have to spell the words in the grid by dragging the letters in from the side.

This code randomly generates 12 words from the "listOfWords" and dynamically creates a 6x6 table. The words are also split into single characters ("P""I""T") so draggable letters can be placed over to spell the words...

```
var listOfWords = ["mat", "cat", "dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "log", "pan", "can", "man", "pin", "gag", "sat", "pat", "tap", "sap", "tag", "gig", "gap", "nag", "sag", "gas", "pig", "dig", "got", "not", "top", "pop", "god", "mog", "cot", "cop", "cap", "cod", "kid", "kit", "get", "pet", "ten", "net", "pen", "peg", "met", "men", "mum", "run", "mug", "cup", "sun", "mud", "rim", "ram", "rat", "rip", "rag", "rug", "rot", "dad", "sad", "dim", "dip", "did", "mam", "map", "nip", "tin", "tan", "nap", "sit", "tip", "pip", "sip", "had", "him", "his", "hot", "hut", "hop", "hum", "hit", "hat", "has", "hug", "but", "big", "bet", "bad", "bad", "bed", "bud", "beg", "bug", "bun", "bus", "bat", "bit", "fit", "fin", "fun", "fig", "fan", "fat", "lap", "lot", "let", "leg", "lit"];

var shuffledWords = listOfWords.slice(0).sort(function () {
return 0.5 - Math.random();
}).slice(0, 12);

var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className='tablestyle';
var wordsPerRow = 2;


for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length; i += wordsPerRow) {
var row = document.createElement('tr');

for (var j=i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++ j) {
    var word = shuffledWords[j];

    for (var k = 0; k < word.length; k++){
        var cell = document.createElement('td');


        cell.textContent = word[k];
        // IF FIREFOX USE cell.textContent = word[j]; INSTEAD
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
}
tbl.appendChild(row);    
}

 document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Here is the code for the draggable letters that are dropped onto the grid to spell the words.

```
<div class="squares">

        <div id="drag1" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style2" tabindex="0">
        <p>a</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag2" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>b</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag3" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>c</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag4" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>d</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag5" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style2" tabindex="0">
        <p>e</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag6" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>f</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag7" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>g</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag8" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>h</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag9" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style2" tabindex="0">
        <p>i</p>
        </div>

         <div id="drag10" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>j</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag11" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>k</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag12" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>l</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag13" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>m</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag14" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>n</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag15" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style2" tabindex="0">
        <p>o</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag16" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>p</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag17" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>r</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag18" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>s</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag19" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>t</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag20" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style2" tabindex="0">
        <p>u</p>
        </div>
```

How do I make the words recognize the correct letters when they are dropped on top?

Something along these lines....

```
if ("mat" == drag13 + drag1 + drag19) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Where do you drag them to ?
Have you considered using sortable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made you a simplified version with drag and drop enabled.
Note that, in this example, it is useless (and inadvisable) to split the words into letters.

I've used HTML5 custom data attributes, but you can also use the id to store the words and letters.

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nsPB/1/) (drag 3 letters to a word)

You should also read [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) on droppable and draggable.