# Turning pseudocode into code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently building a spelling game where you drag the letters onto the word. The word is **"mat"** and **"drag13"** = **"m", "drag1" = "a" and "drag19" = "t".** I need some code that will recognize the letters when they are dropped on the word. Depending on whether it is recognized or not will determine the style given to it by the CSS. Can someone help?

```
if ("mat" == drag13 + drag1 + drag19) {

            return true; (add a css style1)
        }

        else {

            return false; (add a css style2)
        }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. What are you actually asking?

Comment: where you want to add css style, if you have any element then use $(element).css('property','value');

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Can someone help me to write it as I can't get my head around it. Trust me I have tried doing the research myself

Comment: @T.J. Crowder  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11507072/1518070

Comment: remove the word "pseudo"

Comment: @m0onio Its a Joke P. I have given a solution. Please try if it fits ur requirement

Comment: Well it clearly doesn't if I haven't accepted it. Your telling me what I already know. Did you check the link? @madhairsilence

Comment: @m0onio: Being rude to people trying to help you is not a strategy likely to lead to a good result.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder  How is that being rude?

Comment: @m0onio: To me, the entire tone of that seems rude. Just my take.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Just remember that peoples tone doesn't come through in text.

Comment: @Linuxios - No offence intended but sometimes it does and sometimes it also does give out a wrong tone. So, one has to be cautious the way they put it. It is a good practice to be polite and there are words to do that.

Comment: @Shaks: Exactly what I ment. Thank you for the better explanation. You both have to be very careful and polite while saying things, and give the benefit of the doubt when reading them.

Comment: @Linuxios - Well, if you are talking about me, I did say that I don't intend to offend by what I was saying. And it was a generic suggestion to what you said. I don't intend to drag this conversation as this does not help OP. And I don't think I have offended anyone as I tried to choose my words carefully. But thanks for the suggestion anyway. I'll be careful and I guess this holds good for everyone.

Comment: @Shaks: I never said you were rude. Not at all. I was referring to T.J.'s saying that m0onio was rude, and I just wanted to remind him that feelings and tone don't always come out right in text.

Answer (score 1):

```
word = drag13+drag1+drag19;
myDiv = document.getElementById("adiv");
if(word == "mat"){
//do stuff

myDiv.className += " correct";
}else{
//do other stuff

 myDiv.className += " incorrect";
}
```

this is the kind of code you are looking for.

Comment: yes this sort of thing, how would I then apply the css styles to whether it is true or false?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something:

```
if("mat" == (letters[13]+letters[1]+letters[19]))
{
  $(".worddisplay").css('property", 'value');
  return true;
}
else
{
  $(".worddisplay").css('otherproperty", 'othervalue');
  return false;
}
```

Then just make sure that the things that display the words have `class="worddisplay"`, or change the `.`s to `#`s and give the word display `id="worddisplay"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add or remove a CSS class, you can do this with jQuery's [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Answer (score 0):

Simple Idea. Convert in to solution by yourself.

Every letter is a div. And have an attribute (may be ID) and its values is its location(postion) in the screen.

Use jQuery draggable to drag it. When the position of the dragged components match with the DIV, then return it.

Comment: I understand this, but I dont know how to link them when the draggable is dropped on top. Check the link in the comments section above, that is the full question @madhairsilence